# namespace ‘nlme’ 3.1-121 is being loaded, but >= 3.1.123 is required

Tags: r

I'm trying to install RVAideMemoire. I think the package and all its dependencies are installed, but I'm getting a namespace error now.

```
> library(RVAideMemoire)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘nlme’ 3.1-121 is being loaded, but >= 3.1.123 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘RVAideMemoire’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RVAideMemoire’
```

Comment: you may want to check your R version as well.  If you have an old version you could get into dependency troubles ...

Comment: I am no longer able to ask questions on stack overflow because this got two downvotes. Is there any way I can edit the question so I can start asking again?

Comment: In principle, yes: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) . It's surprising that you got a question ban just for one question: "One or two bad posts will not cause you to be blocked from using the site."  I didn't downvote this question (didn't upvote it either), but there doesn't seem to be a lot of scope for improvement (pretty basic question).  You could work on improving your other questions ... Did @CephBirk's answer solve your problem (in which case you should click the check-mark to accept it)?

Comment: ... although the link does say "significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts."  Maybe you could improve some of your zero-voted questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have version 3.1-121 installed but you need to install a later version of `nlme`. The latest version on CRAN is 3.1-128. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/

```
install.packages("nlme")
```

If you run this line with an internet connection then you'll update to 3.1-128 which should solve your problem.